# Cannot apply a VBA Autofilter to a table which I export to a CSV

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with rows that have cells with "" blank?! characters So I try the following to filter those rows

```
Set tbl = Worksheets("FOR EXPORT").ListObjects("TableName")
'SET AUTOFILTER
tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>"
```

But I get the whole table when I do the following

```
'COPY TABLE RANGE TO ARRAY
tblArr = tbl.Range.Value

'SET FILE OUTPUT
fNum = FreeFile()
Open csvFilePath For Output As #fNum

For i = 1 To UBound(tblArr)
    rowArr = Application.Index(tblArr, i, 0)
    csvVal = VBA.Join(rowArr, ";")
    Print #1, csvVal  
Next
```

and not the filtered table which I can see that is applied already to the worksheet

The whole sub is

```
Sub saveTableToCSV()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim csvFilePath As String
Dim fNum As Integer
Dim tblArr As Variant


Dim rowArr

Dim csvVal


Set tbl = Worksheets("FOR EXPORT").ListObjects("TableName")
'SET AUTOFILTER
tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>"

'SET PATH
csvFilePath = "C:\Users\FatherNick\Desktop\CSVFile.csv"
'COPY TABLE RANGE TO ARRAY
tblArr = tbl.Range.Value

'SET FILE OUTPUT
fNum = FreeFile()
Open csvFilePath For Output As #fNum

For i = 1 To UBound(tblArr)

    rowArr = Application.Index(tblArr, i, 0)
    csvVal = VBA.Join(rowArr, ";")
    Print #1, csvVal

Next
'RESET FILTER
'tbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
Close #fNum
Set tblArr = Nothing
Set rowArr = Nothing
Set csvVal = Nothing
End Sub
```

How can I pass to Array the Filtered table and not the whole table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the code below (explanations inside the codes' comments):

```
Dim VisRng As Range

' set the new Range object to the visible cells of `tbl.Range`
Set VisRng = tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

' copy only the visible cells in range to array
tblArr = VisRng.Value
```

Comment: Is it possible to put in criteria everything apart from Error or Specific Error like #REF! ?

Comment: @Nikos you can set a range to Errors with 'tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlErrors)', you can read more about it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells